# Javascript ignores novalidate on number field?

Tags: javascript, html

It seems JavaScript, at least in IE11 and Firefox, ignores the form "novalidate" option when setting the value of a Number field.  I want to use the Number field because I want the number pad to appear in place of the keyboard when my site is viewed on a mobile device, but when a value is entered, I want to be able to format it as (###) ###-####.  In the following example, I can type whatever I want into the field because of the "novalidate" option, but JS will not let me insert what I want:

```js
var txtNum = document.getElementById("txtNum");
function ftnTestA() {
 var num = "1234567890";
 txtNum.value = num;
}
function ftnTestB() {
 var num = "(123) 456-7890";
 txtNum.value = num;
}
function ftnTestC() {
 var num = "123-456-7890";
 txtNum.value = num;
}
```

```html
<form novalidate="novalidate">
 <input type="number" id="txtNum" />
 <br/><br/>
 <button type="button" onclick="ftnTestA();">1234567890 (works)</button>
 <button type="button" onclick="ftnTestB();">(123) 456-7890 (no IE, no FF)</button>
 <button type="button" onclick="ftnTestC();">123-456-7890 (works in IE, no FF)</button>
</form>
```

Comment: In the latest version of chrome it doesn't even let you type the parentheses into that field.  I think there's a more fundamental problem here.  `novalidate` is not doing what you initially thought it was doing.

Comment: `novalidate` doesn't work here. It only shuts off validation if you're using it. The field with an input type 'number' will not accept non-numeric characters. 

You'll need to change your input type to something else, although the correct type escapes me.

Comment: "Javascript" is not ignoring validation; it is the _browser_ that supports (or not) HTML5 form validation and the new HTML5 input types. In your case, the browser _is **not**_ ignoring "novalidate" — it is the input type `<input type="number">` that restricts what can be entered into it, regardless of the form/field validation. Only a restricted set of characters may be entered in that field... try `E`, it's allowed so you can enter a number with scientific notation, like `3.02E+7` or `9.707E-12`

Comment: Without "novalidate", I cannot type parentheses or any other non-numeric in the field manually. With novalidate, I can manually type whatever I want into the field yet still only get the number pad on mobile browsers. This is expected behavior. Yet even though I can manually type whatever I want, using JavaScript to populate the field still follows the restrictions regardless. So novalidate does work and it is possible to enter non-numerics in a number field, at least in FF and IE; it just isn't taken into account by JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the `type="number"` input field, use the `type="tel"` field since that is what you are trying to do. Number input fields are designed for numbers only.

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I needed.